# Select file in dialogue box, place the path in text box, and another button for importing as a table

Tags: vba, ms-access

VBA to open a dialogue box by clicking buttons, select files individually, place the path in more than one text boxes, click another button to import the files

I have been searching on the web but all the codes have both selecting and importing in one program

```vb
'Module
Public Sub ImportDocument()
    On Error GoTo ErrProc

    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With fd
        .InitialFileName = "Some folder"
        .Title = "Some Title"
        With .Filters
            .Clear
            .Add "TXT documents", "*.txt", 1
        End With
        .ButtonName = " Import Selected "
        .AllowMultiSelect = False

        If .Show = 0 Then GoTo Leave
    End With

    Dim selectedItem As Variant
    For Each selectedItem In fd.SelectedItems
        DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "team_Specs", "team", selectedItem, True, ""
        'DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "Raw Data from Import_ Import Specification", "Raw Data from Import", selectedItem, True, ""
    Next

Leave:
    Set fd = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub

ErrProc:
    MsgBox err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Leave
End Sub

'Form
Private Sub Command2_Click()
Dim status_ As TaskImportEnum
    status_ = ImportDocument

Select Case status_
    Case TaskImportEnum.Success:
        MsgBox "Success!"

    Case TaskImportEnum.Failure:
        MsgBox "Failure..."

    Case Else:
        MsgBox "Aborted..."
End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to break down the import sub into multiple tasks.

The Select file Function returns only the file path of the selected document and the path is then inserted into the relevant TextBox.

The import button then validates the TextBox has a value and yes, it imports it.

**1. Select file.**

---

```
Private Sub ButtonSelect_Click()

    Dim file_ As String
        file_ = SelectDocument()

    'Selection was made?
    If file_ <> vbNullString Then TextBoxFilePath.Value = file_

End Sub
```

The Function to select a file.

---

```
Public Function SelectDocument() As String
    On Error GoTo Trap

    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With fd
        .InitialFileName = "Some folder"
        .Title = "Some Title"
        With .Filters
            .Clear
            .Add "TXT documents", "*.txt", 1
        End With
        .ButtonName = " Import Selected "
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
    End With

    'if a selection was made, return the file path
    If fd.Show = -1 Then SelectDocument = fd.SelectedItems(1)

Leave:
    Set fd = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
Exit Function

Trap:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Leave
End Function
```

**2. Import if a selection has been made.**

---

```
Private Sub ButtonImport_Click()
    With TextBoxFilePath
        If Not IsNull(.Value) Then
            DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "team_Specs", "team", .Value, True, ""
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

---

You need to change the names of the Buttons and TextBoxes.

Comment: I got an "Invalid Procedure Call or Argument" error when I run the select button

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you've written?

Comment: Thank you for help in writing this code. I used the exact revised code but changed my Form button name to "ButtonSelect" and another button as "ButtonImport". I am not sure if I need to change my text box name. The table name is team with team_specs as specification

Comment: Just make sure your code compiles. Go into the VB Editor >> Debug >> Compile [your project name]. See if it compiles and if not, it will highlight where the error is.

Comment: It is compiles without any issue

Comment: OK that's good. Place a breakpoint on the first button's click event and follow the code with F8 to see where the error occurs.

Comment: I see the breakpoint but couldn't figure out where I find the event. I did it the way I debug in excel vba by having a breakpoint and clicking run before F8. However, it is not stepping through the lines

Comment: I get an error by clicking the button with the breakpoint:  If file_ <> vbNullString Then TextBoxFilePath.Value = file_

Comment: I also got error from the function line: Resume Leave

Comment: You need to change the TextBox name to the name of your textbox.

Comment: My textbox name is text3 so I changed it to If file_ <> vbNullString Then text3.Value = file_ and If file_ <> vbNullString Then text3FilePath.Value = file_ and in cases,I still got the same error message

Comment: The import button works if I copy and paste the file location in the textbox but when I tried to select the file using the first button I get the error

Comment: Apologies, my mistake. The `fd.SelectedItems` is a collection so the index starts at 1. Change `fd.SelectedItems(0)` to `fd.SelectedItems(1)`.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you so much! Is it possible to have the code import either excel or a text file? If yes, what do I add to the code to accomplish that?

Comment: Add a 2nd filter: `.Add "Excel documents", "*.xlsx", 2`

Comment: What import code do I need to call it and do I create another button for it?

Comment: The `SelectDocument` function will return the path for the selected file, but the method who called it needs to figure out what to do with it. You could check the file extension and act accordingly. `If Right(file_,4) = ".txt" Then... [process text] Else [process excel]`.

Comment: I am thinking it is easier to have separate buttons for excel import but when I enter below code, I get "...File name argument" error.                                                                                     
With Text7

        If Not IsNull(.Value) Then
            DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "testtbl", selectedItem, True, "Original$"
      
        End If
    
    End With
   
End Sub

Comment: Change `selectedItem` to `.Value` since the file path is the value of the textbox.